# Virtualbox fail to start a virtual machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian-stretch

Virtualbox gives me the following output:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine 8.

The VM session was closed before any attempt to power it on.

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: SessionMachine
Interface: ISession {7844aa05-b02e-4cdd-a04f-ade4a762e6b7}
```

Edit: The option "Discard Saved States" is disabled.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1. `cd /home/$user/.VirtualBox/`
2. find the `VirtualBox.xml-prev`, which is a backup of the previous Virtual Box config
   3.remove he current non-working config file
   `rm VirtualBox.xml`
3. Use the previous working config file

`mv VirtualBox.xml-prev VirtualBox.xml`

Source:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/217972/virtualbox-does-not-run-ns-error-failure

Comment: Actually, the file is in /home/$user/.config/VirtualBox/ and it did'nt work out for me.

Answer (score -1):

Solved!
I imported the virtual machine from a previous backup when I wiped the system clean. First I found out that the usb 2.0 configs were conflicting with virtualbox and after solving it I was prompted to install the Extension Pack.
Done!
May the force be with you.